# Pivoting a dataframe that needs to be both wider and longer

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I am working with some government sourced data that has a format that can be replicated with this code:

```r
Names <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5), rep("C",5))
Types <- c(rep(c("Income","Tax Paid","Consumption","Stimulus","NonDurable expenses"),3))
year1 <- c(rep(c(1000,100,300,100,200),3))
year2 <- c(rep(c(2000,200,600,200,400),3))
year3 <- c(rep(c(4000,400,800,400,800),3))
df <- data.frame(Names,Types,year1,year2,year3)
```

What I wanted was to have a new dataframe that would have

| Name | year | Income | Tax | Consumption | Stimulus | NonDurable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | year1 | 1000 | 100 | 300 | 100 | 200 |
| A | year2 | 1000 | 100 | 300 | 100 | 200 |
| A | year3 | 1000 | 100 | 300 | 100 | 200 |
| B | year1 | 2000 | 200 | 600 | 200 | 400 |
| B | year2 | 2000 | 200 | 600 | 200 | 400 |
| B | year3 | 2000 | 200 | 600 | 200 | 400 |

Which goes on like that. So, for every person, have the table long by `year` and use cell names in `Types` as new columns with corresponding values.

I have thought of one way out of handling this: filter out each by Type and have separate data frames for each type then `pivot_longer`, then `bind_cols` the results. But I think this is inefficient.
Here is my code:

```r
df %>% filter(Types == "Income") %>%
      pivot_longer(cols=c(year1:year3), names_to = "Year", values_to = "income") %>% select(-Types) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% filter(Types == "Tax Paid") %>%
              pivot_longer(cols=c(year1:year3), names_to = "Year", values_to = "Tax_paid") %>% select(Tax_paid)) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% filter(Types == "Consumption") %>%
              pivot_longer(cols=c(year1:year3), names_to = "Year", values_to = "Consumption") %>% select(Consumption)) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% filter(Types == "Stimulus") %>%
              pivot_longer(cols=c(year1:year3), names_to = "Year", values_to = "Stimulus") %>% select(Stimulus)) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% filter(Types == "NonDurable expenses") %>%
              pivot_longer(cols=c(year1:year3), names_to = "Year", values_to = "NonDurable_expenses") %>% select(NonDurable_expenses))
```

Can someone help with a better and efficient code?

Comment: Are you really using a package to `cbind`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does what you want

```r
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
(df
    |> pivot_longer(year1:year3, names_to = "year") 
    |> pivot_wider(names_from = Types)
    |> rename_with(~ stringr::str_remove(., " +.*"))
)
```

(The extra parentheses around the whole expression are an odd formatting/stylistic preference of mine; doing it this way allows each line to *start* with a pipe, rather than having to make sure they *end* with a pipe ...)

Comment: Any particular reason for the extra brackets?

Answer (score 4):

A base R option using `reshape` twice

```
reshape(
    transform(
        reshape(
            df,
            direction = "long",
            idvar = c("Names", "Types"),
            varying = -(1:2),
            v.names = "year"
        ),
        time = paste0("year", time)
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = c("Names", "time"),
    timevar = "Types"
)
```

which gives

```
           Names  time year.Income year.Tax Paid year.Consumption year.Stimulus
A.Income.1     A year1        1000           100              300           100
B.Income.1     B year1        1000           100              300           100
C.Income.1     C year1        1000           100              300           100
A.Income.2     A year2        2000           200              600           200
B.Income.2     B year2        2000           200              600           200
C.Income.2     C year2        2000           200              600           200
A.Income.3     A year3        4000           400              800           400
B.Income.3     B year3        4000           400              800           400
C.Income.3     C year3        4000           400              800           400
           year.NonDurable expenses
A.Income.1                      200
B.Income.1                      200
C.Income.1                      200
A.Income.2                      400
B.Income.2                      400
C.Income.2                      400
A.Income.3                      800
B.Income.3                      800
C.Income.3                      800
```

---

With `pivot_*` family from `tidyr`, you can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("year"), names_to = "year") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Types)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 9 × 7
  Names year  Income `Tax Paid` Consumption Stimulus `NonDurable expenses`
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 A     year1   1000        100         300      100                   200
2 A     year2   2000        200         600      200                   400
3 A     year3   4000        400         800      400                   800
4 B     year1   1000        100         300      100                   200
5 B     year2   2000        200         600      200                   400
6 B     year3   4000        400         800      400                   800
7 C     year1   1000        100         300      100                   200
8 C     year2   2000        200         600      200                   400
9 C     year3   4000        400         800      400                   800
```

---

With `data.table`, you can use `dcast` + `melt`

```
> library(data.table)

> dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = c("Names", "Types")), Names + variable ~ Types)
   Names variable Consumption Income NonDurable expenses Stimulus Tax Paid
1:     A    year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
2:     A    year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
3:     A    year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
4:     B    year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
5:     B    year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
6:     B    year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
7:     C    year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
8:     C    year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
9:     C    year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
```

Comment: Nice use of negative varying, +1

Answer (score 2):

In `reshape2` package you'll find useful functions.

```
reshape2:::melt.data.frame(df, 1:2) |> reshape2::dcast(Names + variable ~ Types)
#   Names variable Consumption Income NonDurable expenses Stimulus Tax Paid
# 1     A    year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
# 2     A    year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
# 3     A    year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
# 4     B    year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
# 5     B    year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
# 6     B    year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
# 7     C    year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
# 8     C    year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
# 9     C    year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
```

Or, suggested by *@ThomasIsCoding*, we save 20 bytes and do

```
reshape2::recast(df, Names + variable ~ Types, id.var = 1:2)
```

with same output.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Names = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Types = c("Income", "Tax Paid", 
"Consumption", "Stimulus", "NonDurable expenses", "Income", "Tax Paid", 
"Consumption", "Stimulus", "NonDurable expenses", "Income", "Tax Paid", 
"Consumption", "Stimulus", "NonDurable expenses"), year1 = c("1000", 
"100", "300", "100", "200", "1000", "100", "300", "100", "200", 
"1000", "100", "300", "100", "200"), year2 = c("2000", "200", 
"600", "200", "400", "2000", "200", "600", "200", "400", "2000", 
"200", "600", "200", "400"), year3 = c("4000", "400", "800", 
"400", "800", "4000", "400", "800", "400", "800", "4000", "400", 
"800", "400", "800")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: in `reshape2`, I think you can use `recast`, e.g., `recast(df, Names + variable ~ Types, id.var = 1:2)`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Neat, just learned from `recast` yesterday!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data.table solution:
I must admit the logic was already submitted:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- setDT(df)

dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = c("Names", "Types"), variable.name = "Year", value.name = "Value")
dt_wide <- dcast(dt_long, Names + Year ~ Types, value.var = "Value")
```

```
 Names  Year Consumption Income NonDurable expenses Stimulus Tax Paid
1:     A year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
2:     A year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
3:     A year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
4:     B year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
5:     B year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
6:     B year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
7:     C year1         300   1000                 200      100      100
8:     C year2         600   2000                 400      200      200
9:     C year3         800   4000                 800      400      400
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr` to `pivot_longer` and then `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Names <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5), rep("C",5))
Types <- c(rep(c("Income","Tax Paid","Consumption","Stimulus","NonDurable expenses"),3))
year1 <- c(rep(c(1000,100,300,100,200),3))
year2 <- c(rep(c(2000,200,600,200,400),3))
year3 <- c(rep(c(4000,400,800,400,800),3))
df <- data.frame(Names,Types,year1,year2,year3)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(year1, year2, year3), names_to = "year") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Types, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 7
#>   Names year  Income `Tax Paid` Consumption Stimulus `NonDurable expenses`
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>                 <dbl>
#> 1 A     year1   1000        100         300      100                   200
#> 2 A     year2   2000        200         600      200                   400
#> 3 A     year3   4000        400         800      400                   800
#> 4 B     year1   1000        100         300      100                   200
#> 5 B     year2   2000        200         600      200                   400
#> 6 B     year3   4000        400         800      400                   800
#> 7 C     year1   1000        100         300      100                   200
#> 8 C     year2   2000        200         600      200                   400
#> 9 C     year3   4000        400         800      400                   800
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is fine but identical to my solution ... ??

Comment: Thank you all. Both your solutions work Calum and @Ben. I just had an issue with the last line from Ben's code when using the str_remove function due to some similar variable names. janitor::clean_names() handled that elegantly. Thank you both again.

Comment: The accepted answer should be @Ben Bolker's one. This answer is ok. But the logic is same as that of Ben Bolker.

Comment: Well, `str_remove` works **with the example you provided** ... :-)

Comment: Must have posted right at the same time - I didn't see Ben's answer when I wrote this, but if it was first no big deal.